# Issues Decoding Flate from PDF Embedded Font

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, pdfbox, embedded-fonts

Ok, before we start. I work for a company that has a license to redistribute PDF files from various publishers in any media form. So, that being said, the extraction of embedded fonts from the given PDF files is not only legal - but also vital to the presentation.

I am using code found on this site, however I do not recall the author, when I find it I will reference them. I have located the stream within the PDF file that contains the embedded fonts, I have isolated this encoded stream as a string and then into a `byte[]`. When I use the following code I get an error

```
Block length does not match with its complement.
```

Code (the error occurs in the `while` line below):

```
private static byte[] DecodeFlateDecodeData(byte[] data)
{
    MemoryStream outputStream;
    using (outputStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var compressedDataStream = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
            // Remove the first two bytes to skip the header (it isn't recognized by the DeflateStream class)
            compressedDataStream.ReadByte();
            compressedDataStream.ReadByte();

            var deflateStream = new DeflateStream(compressedDataStream, CompressionMode.Decompress, true);
            var decompressedBuffer = new byte[compressedDataStream.Length];
            int read;

            // The error occurs in the following line
            while ((read = deflateStream.Read(decompressedBuffer, 0, decompressedBuffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                outputStream.Write(decompressedBuffer, 0, read);
            }
            outputStream.Flush();
            compressedDataStream.Close();
        }

        return ReadFully(outputStream);
    }
}
```

After using the usual tools (Google, Bing, archives here) I found that the majority of the time that this occurs is when one has not consumed the first two bytes of the encoding stream - but this is done here so i cannot find the source of this error. Below is the encoded stream:

```
H‰LT}lg?7ñù¤aŽÂ½ãnÕ´jh›Ú?-T’ÑRL–¦
ëš:Uí6Ÿ¶“ø+ñ÷ùü™”ÒÆŸŸíóWlÇ±“ºu“°tƒ¦t0ÊD¶jˆ
Ö   m:$½×^*qABBï?Þç÷|ýÞßóJÖˆD"yâP—òpgÇó¦Q¾S¯9£Û¾mçÁçÚ„cÂÛO¡É‡·¥ï~á³ÇãO¡ŸØö=öPD"d‚ìA—$H'‚DC¢D®¤·éC'Å:È—€ìEV%cÿŽS;þÔ’kYkùcË_ZÇZ/·þYº(ýÝ‡Ã_ó3m¤[3¤²4ÿo?²õñÖ*Z/Þiãÿ¿¾õ8Ü    ?»„O Ê£ðÅ­P9ÿ•¿Â¯*–z×No˜0ãÆ-êàîoR‹×ÉêÊêÂulaƒÝü
```

Please help, I am beating my head against the wall here!

NOTE: The stream above is the encoded version of Arial Black - according to the specs inside the PDF:

```
661 0 obj
<< 
/Type /FontDescriptor 
/FontFile3 662 0 R 
/FontBBox [ -194 -307 1688 1083 ] 
/FontName /HLJOBA+ArialBlack 
/Flags 4 
/StemV 0 
/CapHeight 715 
/XHeight 518 
/Ascent 0 
/Descent -209 
/ItalicAngle 0 
/CharSet (/space/T/e/s/t/a/k/i/n/g/S/r/E/x/m/O/u/l)
>> 
endobj
662 0 obj
<< /Length 1700 /Filter /FlateDecode /Subtype /Type1C >> 
stream
H‰LT}lg?7ñù¤aŽÂ½ãnÕ´jh›Ú?-T’ÑRL–¦
ëš:Uí6Ÿ¶“ø+ñ÷ùü™”ÒÆŸŸíóWlÇ±“ºu“°tƒ¦t0ÊD¶jˆ
Ö   m:$½×^*qABBï?Þç÷|ýÞßóJÖˆD"yâP—òpgÇó¦Q¾S¯9£Û¾mçÁçÚ„cÂÛO¡É‡·¥ï~á³ÇãO¡ŸØö=öPD"d‚ìA—$H'‚DC¢D®¤·éC'Å:È—€ìEV%cÿŽS;þÔ’kYkùcË_ZÇZ/·þYº(ýÝ‡Ã_ó3m¤[3¤²4ÿo?²õñÖ*Z/Þiãÿ¿¾õ8Ü    ?»„O Ê£ðÅ­P9ÿ•¿Â¯*–z×No˜0ãÆ-êàîoR‹×ÉêÊêÂulaƒÝü
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have that problem with only one (or only a limitted number of) PDF files while generally it works ok. Thus, the problem might be with those PDFs. Can you provide a sample?

Comment: @mkl, No, I have never once had this work. I suspect that the issue is how I am trying to convert font object into the stream it is supposed to be from the string that I get it from - but I am not certain.                                                               I take the stream string and put it into a string, then I use "Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringValue);" to convert to a byte array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, for anyone who might stumble across this issue themselves allow me to warn you - this is a rocky road without a great deal of good solutions. I eventually moved away from writing all of the code to extract the fonts myself. I simply downloaded MuPDF (open source) and then made command line calls to mutool.exe:

```
    mutool extract C:\mypdf.pdf
```

This pulls all of the fonts into the folder mutool resides in (it also extracts some images (these are the fonts that could not be converted (usually small subsets I think))). I then wrote a method to move those from that folder into the one I wanted them in.

Of course, to convert these to anything usable is a headache in itself - but I have found it to be doable.

As a reminder, font piracy IS piracy.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason why you're not using the [GetStreamBytes()](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/535/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/PdfReader.cs#l2298) method that is provided with iText? What about `data`? Are you sure you are looking at the correct bytes? Did you create the `PRStream` object correctly and did you get the bytes with `PdfReader.GetStreamBytesRaw()`? If so, why decode the bytes yourself? Which brings me to my initial counter-question: is there a particular reason why you're not using the [GetStreamBytes()](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/535/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/PdfReader.cs#l2298) method?

Comment: Well, the reason is that I am remotely new to iTextSharp and have found little help pointing me in directions like this one. I was unsure as to how to isolate the stream using iTextSharp to pull the stream directly from it - I've been pulling from the text (which is where I suspected my error was) - inside the _stream_ and _endstream_ tags. So, short answer, I didn't know of this method! Thank you, for your help thus far, I was beginning to think I would not get any assistance on this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like GetStreamBytes() might solve your problem out right, but let me point out that I think you're doing something dangerous concerning end-of-line markers. The PDF Specification in 7.3.8.1 states that:

> The keyword stream that follows the stream dictionary shall be
>   followed by an end-of-line marker consisting of either a CARRIAGE
>   RETURN and a LINE FEED or just a LINE FEED, and not by a CARRIAGE
>   RETURN alone.

In your code it looks like you always skip two bytes while the spec says it could be either one or two (CR LF or LF).

You should be able to catch whether you are running into this by comparing the exact number of bytes you want to decode with the value of the (Required) "Length" key in the stream dictionary.